Custom sorting in telerik radgridview winforms filter popup
I have a radgridview winforms column contains integers and strings, I need when I open filter of this column to sort integers first then strings. So if I have for example values{200,51,"abc"} the filter popup shows 51 then 200 then "abc".

If 200 , 51 , and abc are values of same column, it means they are all strings, some of them have numeric characters only and some have non-numeric also. You need to write a function to get the value as string and return a number by trying to parse it as number, and if it fails a large number outside the range of possible values. Then you can sort by the output of this function. If the alpha-numeric values also should be sorted, the above function need to convert the string as a number (outside of the possible number range of course).
